# React Native - unable to solve module - even if path is correct

Tags: javascript, react-native, path

So I tried to use some image inside my javascript code in React Native. This is are my folders:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfMOk.png)

As soon as I try to import it with:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { SimpleAnimation } from 'react-native-simple-animations';
//here i try to import my picture
import iconBright from 'testproject/pictures/iconBright.png';


export default function Welcome() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <SimpleAnimation delay={500} duration={1000} fade staticType='zoom'>
     //also here i am trying to import it but same error
    <Image source={require('testproject/pictures/iconBright.png')}></Image>
    </SimpleAnimation>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {

  },
});
```

And whe I compile it I get always this error:

```
Unable to resolve "pictures/iconBright.png" from "screens\Welcome.js"
```

I tried many different ways from the internet and other stackoverlow suggestions but nothing worked. I also tried:

- ./pictures/iconBright.png
- ../pictures/iconBright.png

But nothing works. Can someone help me or explain me how this path-system works, because I havent found any usefull guides for it yet.

EDIT:
here the error on the device:

```js
Unable to resolve module `../pictures/iconBright.PNG` from `screens\Welcome.js`: 

None of these files exist:
  * pictures\iconBright.PNG(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
  * pictures\iconBright.PNG\index(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You images are in .PNG capital and in the import it's .png

I would rename the images to .png and try

Comment: Hello! I tried it but unfortunatly it did not solve it:(

Comment: have you tried like this `source={require('../pictures/iconBright.PNG')}>`

Comment: yeah but still the error. I copied the wohle one and added it to my post. Maybe it will help

Comment: Have tried with this method `source={{uri:'your_path'}}>`

Comment: thank you very much I do not get the error message anymore, but I do not see the picture. If i Display an Text and save it than the Text appears, but I cant see the picture. Do you know whats the problem?

Comment: what would be the right path for my pictute? I have an Image from my folders inside my post(that link)

Comment: If its still like in the image with .PNG i would try `source={{uri:'../pictures/iconBright.PNG'}}`